# Reduce space between lines WITHIN citations in Tufte margin

Tags: line-spacing, tufte

I successfully reduced the space between lines in `marginfigure` content by adding `\AtBeginEnvironment{marginfigure}{\linespread{0.5}}`, but I'm struggling to do the same for citations.

[image]

I created a MRE here: https://gist.github.com/ericpgreen/ef2ece63ecc3635495d14d13eb38700c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: a]

Add to your preamble before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\@tufte@sidenote@font\@tufte@sidenote@justification\setstretch{0.5}}
\makeatother
```